# Problem preventing form submit using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

I have simple form. I want to use jquery to prevent form submit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchform').submit(function(e) {
         alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
   });
});
```

This works fine in chrome. It just shows me a alert box and does not redirect. But does not work on Firefox or IE9, it shows the alert and then goes ahead with form submission.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: mkk has your correct solution, but I would also recommend calling `preventDefault` *first*.  That way, if there's a Javascript error, the form still won't be submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

into

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already returning `false`, you don't also need any sort of `event.preventDefault()` call at all.

The reason that neither of these seem to work for you is that `event` is undefined, so an exception is thrown when calling `event.preventDefault()`, so the method handler exits prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

```
event.preventDefault();
```

should be

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Try that and see if it fixes the problem.